# Finding OS short date format string in MS-Access/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking for a VBA function that would return the current OS Short date format (ex: `M/d/yyyy`, `dd-MMM-yy`, `yy/MM/dd`, etc.) as a string. I have found such functions for MS Excel on related posts using `Application.International`, but they do not work with MS Access.

I want to be able to show the OS date format in my forms to avoid confusion if '08-11-11' is displayed, for example. Using `CDate()`, my dates are automatically formatted to whatever is set in Windows Date and time settings. However, users might not be aware of that.

Comment: You're afraid users won't know what the date format is on their own machines?

Comment: @KenWhite  I'm afraid they would not be fully aware that MS Access uses the same date format as their OS.

Comment: Force the format - either via mask in the form or using the format function and listing as a string and label the box to make it clear what the format is - maintaing concistency for all users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications Otherwise if you are dead-set on listing and using OS date format settings - see here.  Can be done by using windows API calls. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?33984-How-to-GET-the-system-date-format-from-regional-settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pull it from the registry.

There are many ways, the way I use:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\International\sShortDate")
```

Of course, one could use WinAPI to read the registry too.

If reading the registry is really undesirable, you can always format a distinct date, for example:

```
Format(#2/1/3333#, "Short Date")
```

And then parse the result to get the format